# Ended up messing up my /etc/apt folder

Tags: apt, package-management

While working on an online tutorial I probably messed up my etc/apt/ folder as every time I use apt or apt-get command I get the following error:

```
E: Type '&&' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type '&&' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Any help please

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`

Comment: @wjandrea OP mentioned that in first comment. I have deleted my comments otherwise you would be able to recognize them on your own. Not sure from where he pasted that to that list.:)

Comment: @Kulfy Oh, I see. Muhammad, please [edit] your post to add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `kubernetes.list` is creating problems. Since this file only contains a single line which is obviously not correct so it is better to either delete the file using:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

or open file using nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
```

and put `#` before the line to comment it out. Save file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. and try updating again.